# Regarding writing notes on M.S.E

Tags: discussion, soft-question

I am not sure if this is where I should ask this question, but I am wondering if there is a specific place, on this site, where I can write my math notes  on; using the same latex. I want to know because it looks a lot more clear to me to write notes on this site rather than on paper.

Comment: You can use LaTeX without using math.SE. See, for example, http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Downloads

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 5):

One option that doesn't require the hassle of a $\LaTeX$ package installation is the online editor at [ScribTeX](https://www.scribtex.com/). You can write, save, and compile your code through the website.

I like using it for simple files like notes. An added advantage is that you can log in and work on your file from any computer.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for that! Because I just downloaded the link Qiaochu provided me and it is a hassle to learn how to compile all the files. Thanks again!

Comment: See [Compiling documents online](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online) at TeX.SE for more similar useful links.

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you very much for that link!